# Call to a member function next_sibling() on a non-object

Tags: php, dom, if-statement, conditional-statements, simple-html-dom

I'm using `HTML Dom Parser` to get the contents of `HTML` page.

The page has something like this structure

```
<div id = 'someID'>
    content
</div>
<noscript>
  data that I want to extract
</noscript>
```

So I tried to to extract `<noscript>` tag something like that

```
$noScript = $html->find('<noscript>', 2)->plaintext;
```

it was 3rd `noscript` tag in `HTML`

but it returned nothing.

after that I tried to get the `next_sibling()`

```
$noScript = $html->find('#someID', 0)->next_sibling()->plaintext;
```

it's working just fine, but sometimes there is no `next_sibling` to that ID, in that case it throws `Fatal Error`.

can anybody help me that how can I make it conditional, I mean if `next_sibling()` exist, get it, otherwise ignore it.

I tried to wrap this into `if` statement but nothing came out of box..

help help help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
if($div = $html->find('#someID', 0)){
  $noScript = $div->next_sibling()->plaintext;
}
```

Comment: The `div` is always there, I tried that approach, can you please mention how I can get `<noscript>`'s data directly?

Comment: You can't get it directly with simple, but if you switch to [a lib with full css support](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) You can do: `$html->find('#someID + noscript', 0)`